# Magento2: Stop user registration email notification to customer programmatically

Tags: magento2, customer, email, around-plugin

I want stop email notification for user registration(createuser) programmatically.

We can use plugin, observer, extend createpost controller.
Can anyone please suggest which way is standard to do this programmatically.

I have my custom controller and one is default createpost.
I have to set condition if user comes here from my custom controller then stop email and if customer comes from default controller named createpost then email work as it is.

Here I created plugin for this.

> app\code\My\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification">
    <plugin name="disable-email-notification" type="My\Module\Model\Plugin\EmailNotification" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>   
</config>
```

> app\code\My\Module\Model\Plugin\EmailNotification.php

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Model\Plugin;

class EmailNotification
{
    public function aroundNewAccount(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        return $subject
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your above code working or not ?

Comment: What you want to do? Are you want just stop email for customer notification?

Comment: @RaviSoni it works as expected. Is there some option to send a notification to admin that new customer has registered